# DIV too high in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

My website : http://www.hentaidreaming.com/

***NSFW***

note that right at the top, under the menu links, the "Latest Hentai" and "Latest Doujins" tabs are right under the menu links, instead of being 40px lower like they should.

on Firefox and chrome everything is fine, just on IE this problem

any fix?

Comment: Which browser? They look properly placed in Chrome 8 / Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem fix, just had to add Float Left in the css. darn IE !!